# browser hosted CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, web-applications

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but is it correct that browser (with JavaScript enabled, of course) cannot host a couch db on its own?

In other words, must I have a CouchDB **server** installed on every device which wants to (CRUD) use the data while offline?

Thanks!

Comment: @Adam, seen that one, unsure if it's alive :(

Answer (score 3):

No, this is impossible right now. Still there are some projects like **BrowserCouch**, which try to bring CouchDB functionality to browsers.

A newer effort that is picking up momentum is IDBCouch, https://github.com/mikeal/IDBCouch